# If I'm explicitly using WCHAR strings in my Windows application, should I use the -W functions rather than the TCHAR #defines?

Tags: naming, windows, functions

Basically, `TCHAR` and the associated macros (`_T`/`TEXT`) are only really necessary if you're targeting both ANSI and Unicode, and, like 99.9% of developers out there, the possibility that someone might be using Windows 95,  98 or Me is not really a concern of mine.  I use `WCHAR`, `LP(C)WSTR`, etc. in my applications.

If I'm explicitly using those types, should I also explicitly use the associated functions?

For example:

```
 WCHAR wString[100];
 StringCchCopyW(wString, 100, L"Hello World");
 MessageBoxW(0, wString, L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

As opposed to:

```
 WCHAR wString[100];
 StringCchCopy(wString, 100, _T("Hello World"));
 MessageBox(0, wString, _T(""), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

It's not very likely that a colleague will go into the project and change the character set setting to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set", and while the former code is more explicit in what I'm doing, the latter uses the "well-known" name of the function; they're the same names you expect to see on MSDN documentation, and even verbally, I'd find myself saying "string see-see-ech copy" rather than "string see-see-ech copy double-you", even if that's the function I'm explicitly using in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both equivalent. If you have a large code base, you should follow the same style as the existing project code. This can make it easier to read, search, copy/paste code, and use examples from Microsoft. You can choose whichever one you want for new projects.